# How to use `undo.data` to recreate `pending.data` for TaskWarrior after encountering a disk full condition?

Tags: macos, data-recovery, tasks

When my disk hit 100% TaskWarrior overwrote my `pending.data` with a zero byte file. I have an intact `undo.data` but I can't find a way to "replay" the data in it to get my todo list back in a consistent state.

Does anyone know of a way to get use the `undo.data` to recreate the task list?

I have tried some solutions online, but they depend on the `task merge` command, and that's been deprecated in more recent versions of TaskWarrior.

Comment: The same has just happened to me. I'm not sure whether undo.data is complete enough to provide what you're looking for but anyway I don't think there's an automated way to do that. You'd have to write your own script and test it.